# WordPress HTTP to HTTPS without trailing slash results in double redirect

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, apache, https, mod-rewrite

I have noticed that one of my WordPress powered sites is experiencing double redirects when a user or bot attempts to visit a URL without HTTPS and a trailing slash.

*In short:*

- `http://example.com/contact-us` redirects to `https://www.example.com/contact-us`
- `https://www.example.com/contact-us` redirects to `https://www.example.com/contact-us/`

*My htaccess file looks like this:*

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*What do I need to change to prevent these double redirects occurring?*

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that works for you, but there is generally no need to prevent double redirects.   All browsers and crawlers follow chains of redirects that are reasonable length.   Unless you are finding situations where you have 10 redirects chained together, I wouldn't expect it to cause any problems whatsoever either in terms of users seeing error messages, or SEO.

Comment: Hehe, yep very true, I'm trying hide the notifications I get when using a spidering tool, it finds broken links for me but doesn't have a option to hide warnings regarding this non-issue. Maybe I'll look for a newer app :)

Comment: Or fix your links so they link to the final destination rather than something that redirects.   If the spider can't find it, it can't complain about it.

Comment: Certainly, if these are _internal_ links then the links should be fixed first, rather than _masking_ the problem with a redirect. The redirect would be for any stray inbound links.

Comment: I was having two redirects - one to force SSL and then the next to apply the trailing slash. This brought those into one redirect and it made a difference in the load time of my site. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to get this working by using a snippet provided by [anubhava on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava). If anyone spots a potential issue with this code or has a better and cleaner redirect then please don't hesitate to plonk your code as an answer.

> **[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33002187/1892635)**
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.domain.com [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
> RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ https://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
> ```

*So my .htaccess file now looks like this:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "`RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.example.com[R=301,L]`" - Probably just a typo, but you'll need a space before the flags. I would also include a slash on the end of the substitution, although the browser will fix this.

Comment: @w3dk `include a slash on the end of the substitution` Sorry, what do you mean? where?

Comment: So that line becomes `RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]` (a slash after the hostname). It will work either way, so it doesn't strictly matter, but that's only because the browser fixes the URL by appending a slash if it is omitted.

Comment: @w3dk awesome! and `[R=301,L]` should be come `[R=301, L]` ?

Comment: No, just a space _before_ the flags, ie. `<space>[R=301,L]`. No space inbetween the flags - you'll get a 500 error if you stick a space in there.

Comment: Oh, that's a typo :) the one in production has a space between. I'll update answer.

Comment: I have also added the slash on the rewriterule as suggested, thanks for that again.

Comment: This could be cleaned up. You have `RewriteEngine On` twice and the bottom `IfModdule` is pointless since you assume it is there before and it would not work without it.

Comment: @Itai that part of the htaccess is added by WordPress, often when doing upgrades.