# Is ifModule in htaccess a bad practice?

Tags: htaccess, module

Can someone give me a good reason why users are using `ifmodule` in their htaccess ?

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</IfModule>
# Else, doesn't matter. It's fine anyway. Making business #
```

Isn't this a bad practice ? Why using `ifmodule` if they should be definitively sure they want to use some rules ?

Anyway, is it possible that a module freezes/block/disable suddenly without knowing ?

Comment: Exactly the same principles apply as discussed in [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/112602/1243) to the above/linked [question regarding the use of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/is-checking-for-mod-write-really-necessary). To answer your last question: No.